# How can I return a string from a Google BigQuery row iterator object?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

My task is to write a Python script that can take results from BigQuery and email them out. I've written a code that can successfully send an email, but I am having trouble including the results of the BigQuery script in the actual email. The query results are correct, but the actual object I am returning from the query (results) always returns as a Nonetype.

For example, the email should look like this:

Hello,

You have the following issues that have been "open" for more than 7 days:

-List issues here from bigquery code

Thanks.

The code reads in contacts from a contacts.txt file, and it reads in the email message template from a message.txt file. I tried to make the bigquery object into a string, but it still results in an error.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials")
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from string import Template


def query_emailtest():
    client = bigquery.Client(project=("analytics-merch-svcs-thd"))
    query_job = client.query("""
       select dept, project_name, reset, tier, project_status, IssueStatus, division, store_number, top_category,
       DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), in_review, DAY) as days_in_review
       from `analytics-merch-svcs-thd.MPC.RESET_DETAILS`
       where in_review IS NOT NULL
       AND IssueStatus = "In Review"
       AND DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), in_review, DAY) > 7
       AND ready_for_execution IS NULL
       AND project_status = "Active"
       AND program_name <> "Capital" 
       AND program_name <> "SSI - Capital"
       LIMIT 50
    """)
    results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete. 
    return results #THIS IS A NONETYPE


def get_queryresults(results):   #created new method to put query results into a for loop and store it in a variable
    for i,row in enumerate(results,1):
        bq_data = (i , '. ' + str(row.dept) + " " + row.project_name + ", Reset #: " + str(row.reset) + ", Store #: " + str(row.store_number) + ", " + row.IssueStatus + " for " + str(row.days_in_review)+ " days")
        print (bq_data)

def get_contacts(filename):
    names = []
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        for a_contact in contacts_file:
            names.append(a_contact.split()[0])
            emails.append(a_contact.split()[1])
    return names, emails

def read_template(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
        template_file_content = template_file.read()
    return Template(template_file_content)


names, emails = get_contacts('mycontacts.txt')  # read contacts
message_template = read_template('message.txt')
results = query_emailtest()

bq_results = get_queryresults(query_emailtest())


import smtplib
# set up the SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp-mail.outlook.com', port=587)
s.starttls()
s.login('email', 'password')


   # For each contact, send the email:
for name, email in zip(names, emails):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

   # bq_data = get_queryresults(query_emailtest()) 

    # add in the actual person name to the message template
    message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title())
    message = message_template.substitute(QUERY_RESULTS=bq_results) #SUBSTITUTE QUERY RESULTS IN MESSAGE TEMPLATE. This is where I am having trouble because the Row Iterator object results in Nonetype. 


    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From']='email'
    msg['To']='email'
    msg['Subject']="This is TEST"
  #  body = str(get_queryresults(query_emailtest())) #get query results from method to put into message body 


    # add in the message body
   # body = MIMEText(body)
    #msg.attach(body)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))


  #  query_emailtest() 
  #  get_queryresults(query_emailtest())


    # send the message via the server set up earlier.
    s.send_message(msg)

    del msg
```

Message template:

Dear ${PERSON_NAME},

Hope you are doing well. Please find the following alert for Issues that have been "In Review" for greater than 7 days.

${QUERY_RESULTS}

If you would like more information, please visit this link that contains a complete dashboard view of the alert.

ISE Services

Comment: what error message are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error message per se, but when I try to include the query results in the email, it shows up as "None" in the place of where the results should be

Answer (score 5):

The BQ `result()` function returns a generator, so I think you need to change your `return` to `yield from`.

I'm far from a python expert, but the following pared-down code worked for me.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials")

def query_emailtest():
    client = bigquery.Client(project=("my_project"))
    query_job = client.query("""
       select field1, field2 from `my_dataset.my_table` limit 5
    """)
    results = query_job.result()  
    yield from results # NOTE THE CHANGE HERE

results = query_emailtest()

for row in results:
    print(row.field1, row.field2)
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess my main question would be to make the query results become a string so that I can put it in my email. Is there a function that can make a generator object become a string?

Comment: generator is just the data structure.  `str(row.field1)` should work just fine.  one piece of advice, passing datasets/generators isn't always as easy as it seems.  i would consolidate your query and parsing functions.  In your new function, query the db, loop through the result set and append the values from each row into a list, and then `return` the list from the function.  On your end, this ignores most of the generator logic altogether.

Comment: I'll definitely try that! My main issue is that I keep getting "None" in the email where the query results should be - would this fix that issue?

Comment: not sure about the current status of your code, but looking at the code in the question...the statement `message = message_template.substitute(QUERY_RESULTS=bq_results)` attempts to use `bq_results`.  `bq_results` is set via `bq_results = get_queryresults(query_emailtest())`.  However, the function `get_queryresults()` loops through and prints the contents of your query, it does not return anything, so you won't be substituting anything into your message.  I recommend to refactor into a script without so many functions.  the linear thinking might help you sort your problems.